# Select empty dates for no data dates from Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, union

I have a series of metrics stored by second. I am trying to produce a report that will accomplish the following:

- avg metric by hour
- max per hour
- min per hour
- include the date/time for hours with
  no data

This query almost produces the right results. However, for days there are data, I do NOT want the UNION results that produce null values. I want those to drop off.

```
SELECT HOUR, METRIC, MINIMUM, MAXIMUM FROM (
select
  to_char(day,'DD-MON-YY "-" HH24":00"') AS HOUR,
  round(avg(duration), 2) AS METRIC,
  round(min(duration), 2) AS MINIMUM,
  round(max(duration), 2) AS MAXIMUM
from log_events
where day > to_date('08-NOV-10', 'DD-MON-YY')
  and day < to_date('08-NOV-10', 'DD-MON-YY') + 2
  and company = 'company A'
  and component = 'api layer'
  and event_label = 'execution request'
  group by to_char(day,'DD-MON-YY "-" HH24":00"')
  UNION
  select to_char(trunc(to_date('08-NOV-10', 'DD-MON-YY'))+(level-1)/24, 'DD-MON-YY "-" HH24":00"') HOUR,
     null as METRIC,
     null as MINIMUM,
     null as MAXIMUM
  from dual connect by level <= 48
)
order by HOUR;
```

I am not even sure if this is the correct way to query the data. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an inline table with the hours and left join it to your log_events table:

```
select
  dummy_hours.hour,
  log_aggregate.METRIC,
  log_aggregate.MINIMUM,
  log_aggregate.MAXIMUM
from (
  select to_char(trunc(to_date('08-NOV-10', 'DD-MON-YY'))+(level-1)/24, 'DD-MON-YY "-" HH24":00"') HOUR
  from dual connect by level <= 48
) dummy_hours, (
  select to_char(day,'DD-MON-YY "-" HH24":00"') AS HOUR,
  round(avg(duration), 2) AS METRIC,
  round(min(duration), 2) AS MINIMUM,
  round(max(duration), 2) AS MAXIMUM
  from log_events
  where day between to_date('08-NOV-10', 'DD-MON-YY') and to_date('08-NOV-10', 'DD-MON-YY') + 2
  and day > to_date('08-NOV-10', 'DD-MON-YY')
  and day < to_date('08-NOV-10', 'DD-MON-YY') + 2
  and company = 'company A'
  and component = 'api layer'
  and event_label = 'execution request'
  group by to_char(day,'DD-MON-YY "-" HH24":00"')
) log_aggregate
where dummy_hours.hour = log_aggregate.hour(+)
order by dummy_hours.hour;
```

Comment: It appears there is an error in the statement somewhere. I removed the comma from the SELECT in dummy_hours. I confirmed that both queries work (dummy_hours and log_aggregate) independently. However, when I run the query, I get the error "missing expression".

Comment: I corrected the comma and included a table alias in the ORDER BY (I suspect that was causing the error). Can you confirm?

Comment: I still get the same error. (Missing Expression). I can run each of the queries independently and they work fine. But when combined, I get the error.

Comment: Ah! It was the comma after log_aggregate.MAXIMUM. It works now. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Grmbl, I edited it once again, should be OK now. Good to know it works!